# jQuery how to toggle bootstrap tooltip text on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have four buttons with tooltips. And I need to toggle the tooltip text on click of the link. I can change the tooltip text however I couldn't find how to toggle the text. and is there a way that I can achieve this with minimal code.

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ju07sqa5/2/)

```js
    $('.link1').on('click', function(){
         $(this).attr('data-original-title','Tooltip Changed');
    });
    
    $('.link2').on('click', function(){
         $(this).attr('data-original-title','Tooltip Changed');
    });
    
    $('.link3').on('click', function(){
         $(this).attr('data-original-title','Tooltip Changed');
    });
    
    $('.link4').on('click', function(){
         $(this).attr('data-original-title','Tooltip Changed');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="link link1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip 1">Button 1</a>
    
    <a class="link link2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip 2">Button 2</a>
    
    <a class="link link3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip 3">Button 3</a>
    
    <a class="link link4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip 4">Button 4</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JavaScript/jquery code should be like below in order to change tooltip text on clicking the link.
The way to change tooltip text is to set the title of tooltip , and then you need to show the tooltip on clicking the link.

You can see the working sample at  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6mukafe/3/)

```
$("a").tooltip();

$('.link1').on('click', function() {
  toggleToolTip.call(this, "Tooltip 1", "Tooltip Changed");
});

$('.link2').on('click', function() {
  toggleToolTip.call(this, "Tooltip 2", "Tooltip Changed");
});

$('.link3').on('click', function() {
  toggleToolTip.call(this, "Tooltip 3", "Tooltip Changed");
});

$('.link4').on('click', function() {
  toggleToolTip.call(this, "Tooltip 4", "Tooltip Changed");
});

function toggleToolTip(originalTitle, newTitle) {
  var lastTitle = $(this).attr('data-original-title');
  $(this).attr('data-original-title',lastTitle === originalTitle ? newTitle : originalTitle);
  $(this).tooltip("show");
}
```

Comment: I want the tooltip to toggle. For example, on the first click, the tooltip must be changed. and on the second click tooltip text must be changed to Its original and so on.

Comment: Ok. Let me change the sample then.

Answer (score 0):

**let's try...**

simple tooltip showing by jquery.

```js
$(".item").click(function() {
  $( ".tooltip" ).removeClass( "hide" ); 
  $( ".tooltip" ).addClass( "show" );

})

$(".tooltip").click(function() {
  $( ".tooltip" ).removeClass( "show" );   $( ".tooltip" ).addClass( "hide" );
   
})
```

```css
.item {
  width: 100px;
  Height: 100px;
  background: #EEE;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #EEE;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  display: none;
  z-index: 1999;
}
.tooltip:after {
  content: "X";
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  top:0px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index:988;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  Icon
</div>
<div class="tooltip">Content goes there</div>
```